# How do I get sourcemap files to output to my build folder?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, minify, source-maps

I have a minimal webpack1 config that I've whittled a massive project down to just to reproduce this.

When I run my config with webpack-dev-server it works just fine, except the file is only accessible at `localhost:port/bundle.js.map` not in my local projects `dist` folder.

link to repo with instructions: https://github.com/rublev/webpack-nosourcemaps

webpack.config.base.js

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
        path: path.join(process.cwd(), '/dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        root: path.join(__dirname, ''),
        modulesDirectories: [
            'node_modules',
            'app'
        ],
        extensions: ['', '.html', '.js'] // removing '' makes everything explode
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'webpack-sourcemap',
            template: 'app/index.html'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [],
    }
}
```

webpack.config.production.js

```
var config = require('./webpack.config.base.js')

config.devtool = 'source-map'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    config.entry = {
        main: path.join(process.cwd(), '/app/') + 'app.js',
        vendor: [
            'react',
            'react-dom'
        ]
    }
}

config.output = {
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), '/dist'),
    pathInfo: true,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
}

config.module.loaders = config.module.loaders.concat([
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['babel'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
    }
])

config.plugins = config.plugins.concat([
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(true),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        filename: 'vendor.js'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        compress: {
            warnings: false
        }
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
        }
    })
])

module.exports = config
```

Answer (score 0):

You run this code

`NODE_ENV=production webpack-dev-server ...`

add **-d** flag like this

`NODE_ENV=production webpack-dev-server -d...`

> [Development shortcut](http://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html#pure-cli) **-d**
>
> Equals to `--debug --devtool source-map --output-pathinfo`

Answer (score 0):

Add to your production config `config.devtool = 'source-map';` for the highest quality production source-map.

Other production options are `cheap-source-map`, `cheap-module-source-map`, and `nosources-source-map`.

And it's good that you already have `sourceMap: true` set within your UglifyJsPlugin, or else the source-map files wouldn't be generated.

Resource:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/